# raise ValueError("Cannot convert {0!r} to Excel".format(value))

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, spyder

I am trying to use the `df.dropna` function and I want to nest it multiple times using and by the sign ',' and or by using the sign '|' according to the docs https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html#pandas.DataFrame.dropna.
In my code I am converting a csv file into pandas then I am adjusting the data in the columns

```
df = df[['Lastname', 'Firstname','Company','Title','Willing_to_share','Willing_to_introduce','work_phones','Work_email','Work_Street','Work_City','Work_State','Work_Zip','Personal_Street','Personal_City','Personal_State','Personal_Zip','mobile_phones','Personal_email','Note','Note_Category']]
##print(df)
## Lastname Firstname          Company Title Willing_to_share  \
0       Doe      Jane                                           
1   Malcoun       Joe  8/28/2019 14:29                          
2   Ramirez    Morgan                                           
3     Burki     Roman                                           
4      None    Jordan                                           
5      None                                                     
6  Zachuani     Reemo                                           
7    Suarez   Geraldo     
 Willing_to_introduce work_phones              Work_email  \
0                       5678743546        j@greenbriar.com   
1                             None        ceo@nutshell.com   
2                       3338765438      mramirez@nerdy.com   
3                       5468756098           burki@bvb.com   
4                             None  jordanw45490@gmail.com   
5                             None                   ronny   
6                             None                           
7                             None   

              Work_Street      Work_City Work_State Work_Zip Personal_Street  \
0        54 George street  Ridge Springs         VA    25678                   
1     212 South Fifth Ave      Ann Arbor         MI    48103                   
2              567 one st     Birmingham         AL    45678                   
3  546 fourteen street Nw         Dallas         TX    54678                   
4                                                                              
5                                                                              
6                                                                              
7       456 yellow street                                                      

  Personal_City Personal_State Personal_Zip mobile_phones Personal_email Note  \
0                                              3245687907                       
1                                                    None                       
2                                              6780431874                       
3                                              0983457690                       
4                                                    None                       
5                                                    None                       
6                                                    None                       
7                                                    None                       

  Note_Category  
0                
1                
2                
3                
4                
5                
6                
7
```

I have created the workbooks before the if statement

```
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
wb.title = 'Contacts'
wb2 = Workbook()
ws2 = wb2.active
wb2.title = 'Contacts'
```

I am putting the column headers inside the function. What I am trying to achieve is to find valid rows which must have first name, last name, and at least one phone, or address or email of any type (personal or work) not null. Then I am going to put it inside an excel datasheet. Then the inverse of the function inside a second datasheet

```
r1 = df.dropna(subset=['Firstname', 'Lastname', ('work_phones' or 'mobile_phones') or (('Work_City','Work_Street','Work_State','Work_Zip') or ('Personal_Street','Personal_City','Personal_State','Personal_Zip')) or ('Work_email' or 'Personal_email')])

for r in dataframe_to_rows(r1, index=False, header=False):
   ws2.append(r)


wb.save("Accepted Contacts.xlsx")
```

However I get this error when I run it

```
raise ValueError("Cannot convert {0!r} to Excel".format(value))



ValueError: Cannot convert ['Doe', 'Jane', nan, nan, nan, nan, '5678743546', 'j@greenbriar.com', '54 George street', 'Ridge Springs', 'VA', '25678', nan, nan, nan, nan, '3245687907', nan, nan, nan] to Excel
```

Comment: `subset` can only be an array-like object that contains the labels you want to consider for duplication. If you want some more sophisticated type of de-dupliation, where you consider duplicates of people with the same name, and the same phone number in either field, then you need to reshape your data prior to de-duplication. But again, I'm not entirely sure *what* that syntax is trying to imply, so I think you should create a [mcve] with a small example, a better description of what you're trying to do and the expected output from that example.

Comment: I forgot to put what I wanted to achieve. My mistake

Comment: Answering on the TypeError you receive:
`'a' | 'b'` is evaluated and fails, because `or` is not defined for `str` and `str`.

Comment: I solved the typeerror issue now. I have a Value error instead raise ValueError("Cannot convert {0!r} to Excel".format(value))

Comment: try `for r in dataframe_to_rows(r1.fillna('') ):`to remove the nan values.,

Answer (score 0):

I am new to python and learning basics. I am getting the same error likely in the line highlighted in bold and i suspect its related to float conversion.

The code is just converting a column values by multiplying by 90% and saving the excel in a new sheet

```
import openpyxl as xl
wb = xl.load_workbook('transactions.xlsx') # Load workbook excel
sheet = wb['Sheet1'] # Load Sheet in which you need to work
cell = sheet['a1']
cell = sheet.cell(1,1)

for row in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1):
    cell = sheet.cell(row, 3)
    corrected_price = cell.value * 0.9
    corrected_price_cell = sheet.cell(row, 4)
    **corrected_price_cell.value = corrected_price_cell**

# wb.save('transactions2.xlsx')
```

Comment: When you shared code snippet as answer please try to explain it.

Answer (score 0):

So I´m experimenting with SQL, and openpyxl. Today I got the same error.

For me it was the way SQL parsed my data. Because I have some variable lenght lists on SQL, excel didnt knew where to place them. I fixed my problem, popping the data that was causing troubles and placing it individually. Remember to check first what type of data is your result.